# Sun T5120 not able to boot from USB in ok prompt

Tags: boot, unix, solaris

I have downloaded the `sol-11_4-text-sparc.usb`, then changed the extension from `.usb` to `.bin`, and make it bootable.

It is showing in ok prompt with show-disks commands but not able to boot with USB.

Comment: ?Why not use e.g. "SPARC USB Automated Installer Boot Image" https://www.oracle.com/solaris/solaris11/downloads/solaris11-install-downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

Solaris 11.4 is not supported on the T5120, as documented at:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E60973/glmru.html#SERNSplatformsupport